# java Security filter for Struts Application

Tags: java, struts, servlet-filters

Need your help to write a security filter for a java application which will protect attacks against sql injection and javascript injection.

Any code with examples is fine.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.
Application runs on JDK 1.7 and Struts 1.0.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your filter can have a look at the values in the parameters and attributes.

I think that to set the parameter you might need to jump through some hoops (e.g. have a wrapper class for the parameter, otherwise it's read only??)

So the idea is to check the inputs to make sure they're not doing anything SQL-y or javascript-y.

---

Another approach (regarding SQL injection) is to ALWAYS use procedures and have them look like this:

// very pseudo code

- sql = "SELECT * FROM t_Blargh WHERE icky_ptang = **?**"
- Proc p = connection.getTheThingy(sql)
- p.setParameter(1, thevalueyougotfromtheuser)
- ResultSet rs = p.execute()

same with inserts and updates (and deletes if you do them)

---

So words/phrases to look for and block would be anything like DROP TABLE, SELECT INSERT UPDATE DELETE CREATE javascript script etc.